# Programming Language for Berkeley Overmind Starcraft AI competition

Tags: python, prolog, scheme, lisp, starcraftgym

Does anyone know which programming language the Berkeley Overmind submission to the Starcraft AI competition this past year was?

Comment: You could just email the guys: http://overmind.cs.berkeley.edu/#team

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download all of the bots [here](http://eis.ucsc.edu/BotInstructions).  The Overmind bot is written in Java.

The `bot-Overmind` directory in the distribution contains a large number of Java class files.  It appears to use [bwapi-jbridge](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi-jbridge/wiki/UserGuide_Installation) to bridge the gap between the C++ BroodWar API and the Java code.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? I don't want to use 100MB of their bandwidth just to check.

Comment: @Mark C: I downloaded the bots.  The `bot-Overmind` directory is full of Java classes with names like `edu.berkeley.nlp.starcraft.strategies.ValhallaStrategy`.  I can only offer the certainty of some random guy on the Internet :D

Comment: Thanks, it seemed like you must have actually looked at it, but I wanted to check. I think the blurb above means the framework is written in C++ but can probably be accessed otherwise. P.S.: Can you edit your answer so I can vote it up?

Answer (score 2):

Given no information but the below [quote](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/), I estimate C++:

```
The Brood War Application Programming Interface (BWAPI) is a free and open source C++ framework for creating AI modules for Starcraft: Broodwar.
```

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned above, it was programmed using the BWAPI library, and if it were using Java, I could only assume it was using JNI to interface with the library. If you're looking to use Java for a Starcraft AI, then you should look into JNIBWAPI. If you're looking for other wrappers (such as Prolog or Cython), you should look at [the wrappers section of the BWAPI project section](http://code.google.com/p/bwapi/wiki/Projects#Wrappers)